HubSpot Batch update API
I am using the HubSpot Batch API to update contact properties with a batch size of 50 contacts. However, I've encountered some strange behavior: some contact properties are getting updated as expected, while others are not.
I understand that HubSpot does not update the "update date" if the incoming property value is the same as the existing one. However, in my case, the new values are different from the existing ones, so the properties should be updated. Despite this, some updates are not being applied.
Here is the code I’m using:
    public function updateContactBatch(array $batchData): void
{
    $batchInputs = [];

    foreach ($batchData as $data) {

        if (null === $contact = $this->getContact($data['email'])) {
            return;
        }

        $properties = [
            'example_property_one' => $data['example_value_one'],
            'example_property_two' => $data['example_value_two'],
            'example_property_three' => $data['example_value_three'],
            'example_property_four' => $data['example_value_four'],
            'example_property_five' => $data['example_value_five'],
        ];

        $updateObject = new SimplePublicObjectBatchInput([
            'id' => $contact->getId(),
            'properties' => $properties
        ]);

        $batchInputs[] = $updateObject;

        sleep(1);
    }

    if (empty($batchInputs)) {
        return;
    }

    $batchInput = new BatchInputSimplePublicObjectBatchInput(['inputs' => $batchInputs]);
    sleep(40);
}

Could you provide any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue?
Thank you.
